# How to mount a compact pump onto a full-suspension frame?

Tags: mountain-bike, pump, luggage

Many FS mountain bikes have a weird shaped seat tube. I have managed to strap tube to the bottom of the down tube with electric tape, but am now struggling to purchase and mound a small pump. As is evident from the picture, the bike lacks water bottle mounting screws, where compact frames are typically stored.

What would be a secure mounting option for a pump?

[image]

Comment: Not 'trendy', but a seat bag for spare tube, levers, multitool and a CO2 inflator is hard to beat.

Comment: @mattnz, In both my and a friends experience, saddle bags (filled with a tube and patch kit, not some steel tools) tend to tear after about a week of all-day trail riding. Maybe we chose the wrong bag designs.

Comment: I would suggest velcro straps, though you need some mechanism to keep the pump "centered".  Perhaps some rubber pieces somehow shaped as needed and glued to the frame, to position the pump while held in place with straps.

Comment: @DanielRHicks , maybe I should tie a knot, joining the pump and seat stay, with a piece of a scraped tube.

Comment: I have an older version, shorter travel version of that bike and it has water bottle mounts on both sides of the down tube. My wife has the smallest version of that frame, it still had one set of mounts (outside, near the bottom bracket). What gives?

Comment: If your frame doesn't have bottle cage mounts, perhaps investigate something like the Elite VIP bottle cage clamp? It's effectively a strap-on bottle cage clamp, and your pump could attach to that.

Answer (score 5):

Electric tape is a bad idea because the adhesive can mess with your tube.

Other suggestions

- Many off-road riders carry a hydration pack instead of bottles/bidons.  Carry your spares in the pack.
- Jersey pockets have worked for roadies for many decades.
- Do you have bottle cage mounts?  Either store your tools inside a bottle in the cage, or many mini pumps are sold with a mount point to go between the bottle cage and the frame.
- I have a small triangular frame bag that fits inside the main diamond of my bike.  It carries tube and tools, and a USB battery to power the camera on longer rides.  It straps around the top and down tube by velcro.
- Likewise you can use a top-tube bag, which velcro-straps to your top tube and around the steerer.  Often found with a clear plastic panel on top to hold your phone.  Sometimes referred ti as a Bento, because it can hold food for snacking.
- Not on your bike, but Time Trial bikes with Aerobars can have stuff mounted in the middle of the forearms, with relatively little aero impact.
- Any sort of smallish cloth bag can carry your spares, and then use 2 or 3 velcro cable ties to fasten the bag to the frame where its out of the way, and not going to get dirty.  People who ride downhill would want the weight rear, so on the seatpost or seat.  Those who ride everything prefer weight low in the middle or forward if you do steep climbs.
- Its also possible to load some tools inside handlebars, replacing the end plugs.  Although this can lead to accidental loss of tools and is no good for tubes.
- I read somewhere that the latest Stumpjumper frame has storage compartments in the downtube, which sounds like an interesting idea.
- There are frame pumps that are designed to wedge between a corner and a peg, but your frame probably won't have that.
- Finally - consider not carrying it.   Instead you could carry a smaller CO2 inflator or add sealant to your tyres and trust it will do the job.  Not really recommended.  Further, there's little point carrying tools you can't use, don't fit your bike, or are broken/worn.  Weed out your loadout and take what you need not what you might need.
- If you're out with mates, you don't all need a pump and a multitool.  Just stay together and avoid being separated.

Comment: "Any sort of smallish cloth bag" seems to be the only applicable option for my frame. As is evident from the picture, the front triangle is taken up by the suspension, there are no bottle mount screws and (as is not evident from the picture) the seatpost is adjustable. Probably somehow tied either to the seatstays or the headtube ...

Answer (score 3):

I personally like the saddlebag or backpack option. I keep all my tools and extras in my hydration bag.

BUT...

You could use removable ties and attach it to you seatpost assuming its a small enough pump.

Niteize makes a product called gear ties in an assortment of sizes that are basically industrial twist ties, rubber coated thick wire that holds quite well.

The website info can be seen [here](https://www.niteize.com/product/Gear-Tie-Loopables-6.asp)

They look something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can ask your local bike shop to drill and tap water bottle mounts for you.

With an alu frame the mounts may not be strong enough for water bottles but they are certainly strong enough for a pump, especially with a Velcro backup strap.

Do not do this on a carbon frame. :)

Comment: Nut-serts or Riv-nuts can be used to provide a longer thread too, but the tool needs some space to work so it may not fit inside the smaller frames.

Answer (score 0):

There's [this thing, the Twofish Megablock XL.](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001F307JK) I have no idea how well it works, but it's trying to solve the problem in question. Also, any of the Topeak pump brackets that use their ziptie-esque straps, such as the Mountain Morph, are capable of going on large irregular tubes, although whether there's room on the frame is another question.

Answer (score 0):

There's always [gaffer tape](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaffer_tape).  Gaffer tape is similar to duct tape, and often confused with duct tape.  For many uses, gaffer tape is a much superior product: it's cloth tape rather than plastic tape, so it tears much more easily while offering excellent strength, and it has a synthetic adhesive, so usually when the tape is peeled off there is no adhesive residue left behind.  The downside of gaffer tape is that it costs much more than duct tape.  For those in the US, Guitar Center stocks gaffer tape for about $10 and up.  I probably wouldn't buy a roll just to strap a pump to a bike, but once I bought a roll I found all sorts of other uses for it, such as taping drawers shut when a toddler was visiting, where duct tape just wouldn't have been acceptable.

As a bonus, gaffer-taping a mini-pump to the frame is consistent with [The Rules](http://www.velominati.com/the-rules/), according to [Rule 30](http://www.velominati.com/the-rules/#30), "when no C02 cannisters [sic] are available and your pockets are full of spare kit and energy gels."  (I'm skeptical about the picture actually, because that looks like duct tape rather than gaffer tape.)

[image]